# Easy share action for sharing mp4 files on Facebook with Android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, share, mp4

I want to be able to share a mp4 file in facebook with facebook sdk 4.0 in an android app is it possible? Shall I use open graph instead?

Comment: Facebook is not hosting files for you. You only share an URL as a reference to the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, share an mp4 this way. Try using another social network I don't know if twitter can do the job